# AWS ALB ingress and Nginx ingress in a single cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, amazon-eks, nginx-ingress

I have a quick question on Kubernetes ingress. I have both Nginx ingress controller and AWS ALB ingress controller and ingress resources for both Nginx and AWS ALB in a single cluster. Both of these ingress resources are pointed to a single service and deployment file, meaning, bothe the ingress resources are pointed to the same service. However, when I hit the Nginx ingress URL, I'm able to see the desired page, but with the AWS ALB ingress, I can only see the apache default page. I know this doesn't sound practical, but I'm trying to test out something with both these ingress resources. Just wanted to understand, where am I missing out on seeing the application for AWS ALB ingress URL.

Comment: Where is apache in your stack? It sounds like the backend service is using apache and expecting a specific hostname, outside of ingress configs.

Comment: Could you please provide the exact steps, manifest that you've followed/created to get to this point? It'd definitely shed some light on what exactly you would like to implement.

Comment: Thanks Dawid. I was able to figure out the issue. AWS ALB Ingress was pointing to the default apache document root in the pod. I modified the document root to the application data and was able to see my application page open up!

Comment: @BhargavMg glad that you've managed to find the solution to your issue. Please provide the answer to your question to indicate how you've managed to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Posting this community wiki answer to point that the issue to this question was resolved in the comments.

Feel free to edit and expand.

---

The solution to the issue:

> AWS ALB `Ingress` was pointing to the default `apache` document root in the pod. **I modified the document root to the application data** and was able to see my application page open up!

---

Additional resources that could be useful in this particular example:

- *[Tecmint.com: Change root directory of a apache web server](https://www.tecmint.com/change-root-directory-of-apache-web-server/)* - how to change the `apache2`: `DocumentRoot`
- *[Github.com: Kubernetes sigs: AWS load balancer controller: Docs: Examples](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/aws-load-balancer-controller/tree/main/docs/examples)* - examples of `ALB` that satisfies `Ingress` resource.